# Filtering Sharepoint Lists on a "Now" or "Today"

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to find an effective method of filtering Sharepoint lists based on the age of an item.  In other words, if I want to find list items that are 7 days old, I should be able to build a filtered view on the data.

There is [a hack to build a "Today" field that works](http://blogs.msdn.com/cjohnson/archive/2006/03/16/552314.aspx), but doesn't filter properly.

Does anyone have any good ideas?

Comment: You CAN build a view that filters by Today. You CAN'T build a calculated column that filters by Today, because SharePoint remembers "Today" as "The day you built or last modified this Calculated Column". Ugly hacks are just that, and not reliable besides.

Comment: Today is case sensetive

Comment: Ryan's answer below is the real answer. using "is greater than or equal to"   rather than "less than" No need to modify data structure to get reporting results. Remember NO SPACES eg [Today]-7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this: create a Computed column, called 'Expiry', with a formula that amounts to '[Created] + 7 days'. Then use the computed column in your View's filter. Let us know whether this worked or what problems this poses!

Comment: The idea here is that using [Today] in View filters usually works, compared to having a pseudo column that 'stored' always the current time. So you can instead have your computed column, as described above, and compare that to Today in your View's filtering.

Comment: Error: "Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me."

Answer (score 70):

If you want to filter only items that are less than 7 days old then you just use

Filter

- Created
- is greater than or equal to
- [Today]-7

**Note** - the screenshot is incorrect.

[image: New items - created in last 7 days]

[[Today] is fully supported in view filters](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/the-truth-about-using-today-in-filters/) in 2007 and onwards (just keep the spaces out!) and you only need to muck around with calculated columns in 2003.

Comment: +1. This also lets you filter on a date range without complex xsl by using "greater than or equal to [Today] AND less than or equal to [Today]+x". So only items dated between today and x days from today are exposed.

Comment: Actually, to only show items that are less than a week old, you would choose "is greater than or equal to" vice "is less than". Your example would return all items created MORE than a week ago.

Comment: @CigarDoug versus not vice, or vs., the abbreviation.

Comment: Apparently there is some debate on whether vice is appropriate, meaning "in place of", where some argue "versus" implies opposition. I don't know where I picked it up. But Merriam-Webster agrees with me:

vice -  preposition \ˈvīs also ˈvī-sē\
Definition of VICE


:  in the place of <I will preside, vice the absent chairman>; also :  rather than

Comment: ** (just keep the spaces out!)  FTW!! **

Answer (score 1):

In the View, modify the current view or create a new view and make a filter change, select the radio button "Show items only when the following is true", in the below columns type "Created" and in the next dropdown select "is less than" and fill the next column [Today]-7.

The keyword [Today] denotes the current day for the calculation and this view will show as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Warning about using TODAY (or any calcs in a column).

If you set up a filter and have JUST [Today] it it you should be fine.

But the moment you do something like [Today]-1 ... the view will no longer show up when trying to pick it for alerts.

Another microsoft wonder.

Comment: Create another view then?

Answer (score -2):

Pass Today as value as mentioned below in $viewQuery property :

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://sitename"
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList($listtitle)
write-host "Exporting '$($list.Title)' data from '$($web.Title)' site.."
$viewTitle = "Program Events" #Title property
#Add the column names from the ViewField property to a string collection
$viewFields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
$viewFields.Add("Event Date") > $null
$viewFields.Add("Title") > $null
#Query property
$viewQuery = "<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'><Today/></Value></Geq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EventDate' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>"
#RowLimit property
$viewRowLimit = 30
#Paged property
$viewPaged = $true
#DefaultView property
$viewDefaultView = $false
#Create the view in the destination list
$newview = $list.Views.Add($viewTitle, $viewFields, $viewQuery, $viewRowLimit, $viewPaged, $viewDefaultView)
Write-Host ("View '" + $newview.Title + "' created in list '" + $list.Title + "' on site " + $web.Url)
$web.Dispose()
```